# Increase tmpfs size more than available RAM Is that a good option?

Tags: linux, redhat

Is it advisable to increase the size of tmpfs `/dev/shm` more than available RAM. Will it crash the machine?

The reason for the excercise is to optimize the perfromance of the SAP application.

```
Assume:Current RAM is 64GB.
By default /tmpfs is 50% of RAM - 32GB

Current Requirment of /tmpfs - 150 GB
```

Comment: if you write more then available, i think you know, your server will have same problem

Comment: @c4f4t0r Thanks for the quick response. Is there a recommended ratio between RAM size and /tmpfs other than the default 50%?

Comment: i don't see any recommend.

Comment: How will this optimize performance?  The /tmpfs will be swapping out memory to disk constantly, this would serve no benefit to performance.  The benefit of performance from /tmpfs comes from the use of RAM.  If you have a /tmpfs larger than your RAM size, there will no longer be a benefit.  It will probably decrease performance due to overhead.

Comment: Who told you to do this?

Comment: @Devon Sorry for the late reaction. Tmpfs won't "swap constantly", it will only swap if the data on it is actually used. Using the example scenario in my answer, if you have an 1GB machine, with a 16GB used tmpfs space. If there is a process what uses only, for example, 100MB on this space (for example, an actively updated database table), then only this 100MB will be in ram, the remainder will be in disk (in your swap partition), and your system won't swap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give so many data into your tmpfs, as you wish. There is *no* difference between tmpfs instances in their maximal usage limits. You can even change this easily by a simple remount.

What in the case of the tmpfs counts, it is actual usage.

Tmpfs, against ramfs, *is capable to swap out its content*. Thus, the statement, that "you can't have a tmpfs much bigger as your physical ram", is simply false. For example, you can have as big tmpfs as you wish - if you have enough free swap space. You can have a 16GB tmpfs with a single GB of ram - although it can cause your system to a little bit of overload, similarly as if you would run a process with 16GB ram on an 1GB machine.

In the daily practice I never meet a single case, as a big tmpfs had been required. In this cases I used always normal filesystem space (mostly below `/tmp`). But the possibility exists and you can use it if would be needed.